# Python: Debo usar "shebang" en scripts que corren en entornos virtuales (venv)?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Si mis scripts en Python3 van a correr dentro de un entorno virtual (venv):

```
python3.6 -m venv myvenv
```

Tiene sentido incluir "shebang" como primera línea?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Si así fuera, debo incluir shebang apenas en los scripts que serán ejecutados?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

O también es recomendable incluirla en los scripts que serán importados?

```
from this import that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` ejecuta el comando `env`, el cual a su vez sirve para ejecutar otro comando que le pases a continuación (en tu caso `python`) en un _entorno _.

El entorno es el conjunto de variables de entorno que en ese momento tenga el shell que está ejecutando al comando `env`, y opcionalmente más variables que quieras fijar como parte del comando `env`.

En la práctica, sirve para poder ejecutar un comando (en tu caso `python`) sin tener que especificar la ruta concreta hasta el ejecutable, pues `env` toma de las variables de entorno el valor de la variable `PATH` y lo utiliza para buscar el comando en cuestión.

Por tanto `/usr/bin/env python` usará el valor de `PATH` y ejecutará el primer `python` que encuentre en esa variable. Dentro de un entorno virtual el `PATH` ha sido modificado para que incluya al principio la carpeta donde está el entorno virtual, de modo que el primer `python` que encontrará será el de ese entorno y por tanto funcionará correctamente. Si el entorno no estuviera "activado" entonces el valor del `PATH` no estará modificado y el python que ejecutará será otro.

Te preguntarás por qué tanta complicación, pues a fin de cuentas cuando desde el shell pones `python` a secas ya obtienes ese mismo comportamiento (el `python` ejecutado es el primero que aparece en el `PATH`). Efectivamente, eso ocurre cuando lo lanzas desde el shell, pero no es válido poner un *shebang* que no especifique la ruta absoluta hacia el ejecutable. Es decir, esto no funcionará:

```
#!python
print("Hola mundo!")
```

pues dará el error `-bash: ./script.py: python: intérprete erróneo: No existe el archivo o el directorio`

Esto sí funcionará:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hola")
```

pero en este caso estamos **forzando** a un intérprete python particular, el que se halle en `/usr/bin/`, y no funcionará por tanto con tus entornos virtuales.

En cambio esto funciona como queremos:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hola")
```

pues estamos dando la ruta absoluta hacia el ejecutable, con lo que el shell estará contento, pero ese ejecutable en vez de ser python es `env`, el cual se ocupa de lanzar a Python y para ello *sí* usará la variable `PATH` y por tanto podemos afectar qué python será el que se ejecute según qué valor tenga `PATH` antes de lanzar ese programa.

Answer (score 1):

La única finalidad real de usar un [shebang](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) es si utilizas el script en entornos Unix/Linux y se trate además de un Script ejecutable. La finalidad es, siempre y cuando  el script tenga permisos de ejecución, poder invocarlo sin tener que indicare el interprete.

El sheebang óptimo es el que has indicado

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Si lo tuvieras agregado (por ejemplo) en `mi_script.py`, podrías invocarlo directamente:

```
# ./my_script.py
```

En cuanto a tus dudas *¿Tiene sentido incluir "shebang" como primera línea?* sí, en cualquier script que sea ejecutable es una buena práctica incluirlo, aún bajo entornos Windows, ya que es totalmente inocuo agregarlo. En cuanto a *¿O también es recomendable incluirla en los scripts que serán importados?*, si estos Scripts además podrían ser eventualmente ejecutados de forma independiente, si, pero si son simples paquetes importables, no tiene mucho sentido, pero de todas formas, te repito, es un código inocuo, apenas un comentario más.

Comment: Patricio, y respecto al entorno virtual, qué te parece? Será que `/usr/bin/env python` va a localizar el interpretador correcto, aquél que fue instalado junto con `venv`?

Comment: Bueno, hice un test aquí, y aparentemente sí, usa la versión de interpretador correcta, en mi caso `python3.6` que fue determinada al momento de crear el entorno virtual.

Comment: @AleD, `/usr/bin/env`  es un comando que busca en las variables de entorno la herramienta apropiada, en este caso para ejecutar `python`, es totalmente compatible con los entornos virtuales ya que estos últimos trabajan justamente configurando las variables de entorno, por ejemplo el `PATH`